# Why does the animation plot provide a different plot than the static plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

Good morning,

I am creating an animation by connecting 6 nodes coordinates at 10 different time steps.

I start with a test: I first create a static plot for a time equal to 2 (for example) and I get the exact static plot that I am expecting: all and only the consecutive nodes are connected.

Then I create the animation. Unfortunately, the animated plot connects the nodes in the wrong way. You can see that the animation connects the consecutive nodes, but also the second and the second to last nodes.

Any idea why?
Thanks

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.matrices import Matrix
from sympy import *
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

XrevIn ={0: np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), 1: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  5.55359908e-04, -3.01575613e-03,  1.60258981e-16,
       -1.88004554e-04,  2.09716270e-03]), 2: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  1.88126596e-03, -1.05864905e-02, -5.58856185e-16,
       -4.70983730e-04,  7.78577515e-03]), 3: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  3.07636263e-03, -1.87148693e-02, -5.14379270e-15,
       -1.31916812e-04,  1.52415555e-02]), 4: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  3.58779033e-03, -2.46245242e-02, -1.47128149e-14,
        1.16749245e-03,  2.24516459e-02]), 5: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  3.59200704e-03, -2.82502801e-02, -2.68351002e-14,
        3.02481425e-03,  2.74174357e-02]), 6: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  3.61539600e-03, -3.07970908e-02, -3.72823119e-14,
        4.66788533e-03,  2.80947705e-02]), 7: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  4.03493648e-03, -3.35061989e-02, -4.36533446e-14,
        5.62638096e-03,  2.43037541e-02]), 8: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  4.51964999e-03, -3.52398245e-02, -4.74131398e-14,
        6.20457916e-03,  1.67064087e-02]), 9: np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  4.38242376e-03, -3.39748202e-02, -5.25545111e-14,
        7.17612086e-03,  7.36607871e-03])}
XrevFin ={0: np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), 1: np.array([ 5.55359908e-04, -3.01575613e-03,  1.60258981e-16, -1.88004554e-04,
        2.09716270e-03,  0.00000000e+00]), 2: np.array([ 1.88126596e-03, -1.05864905e-02, -5.58856185e-16, -4.70983730e-04,
        7.78577515e-03,  0.00000000e+00]), 3: np.array([ 3.07636263e-03, -1.87148693e-02, -5.14379270e-15, -1.31916812e-04,
        1.52415555e-02,  0.00000000e+00]), 4: np.array([ 3.58779033e-03, -2.46245242e-02, -1.47128149e-14,  1.16749245e-03,
        2.24516459e-02,  0.00000000e+00]), 5: np.array([ 3.59200704e-03, -2.82502801e-02, -2.68351002e-14,  3.02481425e-03,
        2.74174357e-02,  0.00000000e+00]), 6: np.array([ 3.61539600e-03, -3.07970908e-02, -3.72823119e-14,  4.66788533e-03,
        2.80947705e-02,  0.00000000e+00]), 7: np.array([ 4.03493648e-03, -3.35061989e-02, -4.36533446e-14,  5.62638096e-03,
        2.43037541e-02,  0.00000000e+00]), 8: np.array([ 4.51964999e-03, -3.52398245e-02, -4.74131398e-14,  6.20457916e-03,
        1.67064087e-02,  0.00000000e+00]), 9: np.array([ 4.38242376e-03, -3.39748202e-02, -5.25545111e-14,  7.17612086e-03,
        7.36607871e-03,  0.00000000e+00])}
YrevIn= {0: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       , 0.66666667,
       0.83333333]), 1: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.3338049 , 0.50357479, 0.66666667,
       0.83326732]), 2: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.33505893, 0.5112853 , 0.66666667,
       0.83306314]), 3: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.33664188, 0.51530559, 0.66666667,
       0.83273491]), 4: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.3381702 , 0.51143456, 0.66666667,
       0.83241501]), 5: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.33945781, 0.50276058, 0.66666667,
       0.8324297 ]), 6: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.34040272, 0.49593938, 0.66666667,
       0.83320099]), 7: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.3410492 , 0.49513911, 0.66666667,
       0.83481925]), 8: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.34132823, 0.49705117, 0.66666667,
       0.83704576]), 9: np.array([0.        , 0.16666667, 0.34121215, 0.49408055, 0.66666667,
       0.83932395])}
YrevFin ={0: np.array([0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       , 0.66666667, 0.83333333,
       1.        ]), 1: np.array([0.16666667, 0.3338049 , 0.50357479, 0.66666667, 0.83326732,
       1.        ]), 2: np.array([0.16666667, 0.33505893, 0.5112853 , 0.66666667, 0.83306314,
       1.        ]), 3: np.array([0.16666667, 0.33664188, 0.51530559, 0.66666667, 0.83273491,
       1.        ]), 4: np.array([0.16666667, 0.3381702 , 0.51143456, 0.66666667, 0.83241501,
       1.        ]), 5: np.array([0.16666667, 0.33945781, 0.50276058, 0.66666667, 0.8324297 ,
       1.        ]), 6: np.array([0.16666667, 0.34040272, 0.49593938, 0.66666667, 0.83320099,
       1.        ]), 7: np.array([0.16666667, 0.3410492 , 0.49513911, 0.66666667, 0.83481925,
       1.        ]), 8: np.array([0.16666667, 0.34132823, 0.49705117, 0.66666667, 0.83704576,
       1.        ]), 9: np.array([0.16666667, 0.34121215, 0.49408055, 0.66666667, 0.83932395,
       1.        ])}





dt=0.0005

fig = plt.figure()
line1 =plt.plot([XrevIn[2], XrevFin[2]], [YrevIn[2], YrevFin[2]])
plt.show()


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False,xlim=(-0.1, 0.1),  ylim=(-0.1, 1.1))
ax.grid()
line1, =plt.plot([], [])

time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
def animate(q):  
    line1.set_xdata([XrevIn[q], XrevFin[q]])  
    line1.set_ydata([YrevIn[q], YrevFin[q]])  
    time_text.set_text(str(round((q*dt), 4))+'s')
    return line1, time_text



ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 10),
                              interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your static plot, you have actually created a list of `Line2D` objects (try printing `line1` and you will see its not a single instance).

But, in the animation function, you just create a single `Line2D` instance to set the `xdata` and `ydata` for.

We can change to creating a list of `Line2D` instances, then loop over them and set the appropriate x and y data for each segment like so:

```
lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for i in line1]

time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
def animate(q):  
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        line.set_xdata([XrevIn[q][i], XrevFin[q][i]])  
        line.set_ydata([YrevIn[q][i], YrevFin[q][i]])  
    time_text.set_text(str(round((q*dt), 4))+'s')
    return lines + [time_text]
```

[image]